# How to check variable during a loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, do-while

I know this has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find any topic, so I'll open this one.

In this code, I have an ArrayList of Strings (**coda**) and an Array of String that I use to split each element of the ArrayList. On each iteration of the for, I have an element given to a class (either WorkerRSR, WorkerLRSR or both) and those class will do stuff that is not relevant. What I'd like is to have the do-while after the for's closing curly bracket to works.

Do-While details:
This is needed to be sure that every string has been fully processed by the classes. Every class, after each run, would increase the variable number by one so that I knew when all of the elements were done. Unfortunatly, a do-while like that freeze the entire program.

Is there a way to check the variable during the loop? I know I should probably use threads; I checked them too but it didn't help that much..

```
//Let's pretend I have a fixed number or elements (3)
public static  Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(-2,true);
[...]
if (src == execoda){
        if (coda.size()==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La coda è vuota. Aggiungere elementi alla coda", "Attenzione",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("inizio for "+sem.availablePermits());
            codatof = false;
            for (int i = 0; i<coda.size(); i++){
                String[] tmp = ((String)coda.get(i)).split("-");
                algo = tmp[6];

                if(algo.equals("RSR")){
                    File[] folders = {new File(urlFrames+"\\finalRSR"),};
                    folders[0].mkdir();
                    //parametri WorkerRSR: String urlImg, int dist, int numI, int spra, String algo (6), String urlFrames (7)
                    WorkerRSR workerRSR = new WorkerRSR(tmp[0],Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]),tmp[6],tmp[7]);
                    workerRSR.execute();
                }
                else if(algo.equals("LRSR")){
                    File[] folders = {new File(urlFrames+"\\finalLRSR"),};
                    folders[0].mkdir();
                    //parametri WorkerLRSR: String urlImg, int dist, int numI, int spra, String algo, String urlFrames
                    WorkerLRSR workerLRSR = new WorkerLRSR(tmp[0],Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]),tmp[6],tmp[7],Integer.parseInt(tmp[4]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[5]));
                    workerLRSR.execute();                       
                }
                else if(algo.equals("R+L")){
                    //eseguo entrambi
                    File[] folders = {new File(urlFrames+"\\finalRSR"),new File(urlFrames+"\\finalLRSR")};

                    //eseguo RSR
                    folders[0].mkdir();
                    WorkerRSR workerRSR = new WorkerRSR(tmp[0],Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]),tmp[6],tmp[7]);
                    workerRSR.execute();

                    //eseguo LRSR
                    folders[1].mkdir();
                    WorkerLRSR workerLRSR = new WorkerLRSR(tmp[0],Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]),tmp[6],tmp[7],Integer.parseInt(tmp[4]),Integer.parseInt(tmp[5]));
                    workerLRSR.execute();           
                }
                System.out.println("fine for "+sem.availablePermits());
            }
            codatof = true;                 
        }

//trying to acquire
        try {
            sem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Coda Eseguita", "Attenzione",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

EDIT: Here it is the body of the two Workers. It's not the full code, I'm not including the builder and other stuff that would make it pointlessly longer.
The main difference between the two workers is that the RSR one will call a class called "MakeRSR" while the LRSR one will call exe file called "LRSR.exe"

WorkerRSR (done method):

```
@Override
    protected void done() {
        PanelRSR_LRSR.getProgessbar().setIndeterminate(false);
        if (codatof) //codatof will be false
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Finito RSR", "Attenzione",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        else{
            CreateOption.sem.release();
            System.out.println("Semaforo liberato");
        }
        System.out.println("Algoritmo RSR esguito");
        System.out.println("L'output e' stato salvato in: "+ urlFrames+"\\finalRSR ");
        System.out.println("RSR sem "+CreateOption.sem.availablePermits());
    }
```

Comment: AH, so you are using SwingWorkers. In this case, you cannot use Thread.join() instead, I'd advise you to use a Semaphore (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) start it with a negative count (1 - coda.size()), call acquire() in your main thread and release() in your SwingWorker threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Worker classes are processing the data synchronously (ie on the same thread) then it is guarenteed that all strings will have been processed when you exit your for loop. If the worker classes are performing asynchronous operations, the best solution would be to use an ExecutorService, which you can use to wait and report when all jobs have finished. The reality is that ExecutorService is a framework around Thread.join, which you could also potentially use to wait until all async operations are complete.

----- edit -------

AH, so you are using SwingWorkers. In this case, you cannot use Thread.join() instead, I'd advise you to use a Semaphore (docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/…) start it with a negative count (1 - coda.size()), call acquire() in your main thread and release() in your SwingWorker threads

Comment: The Worker classes are indipendent by each other. They just receive a string and process it. That's why I thought about incrementing a variable in the common calling class.
Another "problem" is that Workers classes use SwingWorker's execute() method which, correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't return anything..

Comment: Independent of each other is not the same as running asynchronously. Asynchronously means in another thread.

Comment: I'm editing the opening post and add the code of the two classes which are both pretty short and similar.
Hope it will make things easier :D
Thanks!

Comment: I'm reading the documentation (this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire() ), and it says that when I acquire a permit, the total number is reduced by one.
So why should I use a negative count? If I start with a negative one and then I reduce this number every time I take a permit, it's never going to 0.. right?

Comment: @pedro you start with a negative count, and release at the end of each worker's processing. So if the length of `coda` is 5, you start all those jobs and initialize your semaphore to -4, your main method is going to wait until all 5 jobs have completed (at which point the semaphore value will be 1) and then it will proceed

Comment: Ok, I made some tests and I had some trouble:
If I want to allow the Worker classes to release the semaphore, I have to declare it public and static, right? But then, if I can't declare in the middle of the code, i can't give it the ArrayList size because that's not a fixed value;
Anyway, I wanted to try, so I set the sem to 100 and then I put a wile(sem.availablePermits()<100). I hoped that it would wait until all the resources were free; but of course it froze.
I also tried to let the main process acquire all the sem but it froze again.
How do I make it wait untill everything is done?

Comment: This isn't a coding issue. You're not understanding how to use semaphores to control process flow.

Comment: For what I understood, I declare a semaphore with n permits. Each acquire() takes one and each release() release one. So, If I understood what you're saying, you suggest to declare a semaphore "already acquired", and then release each permit every time a Worker ends it's job. By doing so, after all the jobs are done, I should end with the semaphore counter set to 1, right? But then, to make the calling class wait for the semaphore value to be 1, do I have to let him acquire a permit? Or how do I make it wait?

Comment: Ah, So you do have the right idea! If you call Semaphore.acquire from "the calling class" it will wait until the semaphore value is 1, ie after all the jobs are done. To state again: You make it wait by calling acquire() on the semaphore when it has less that 1 value; it will return after all jobs are finished, when the semaphore will temporarily have a value of 1, before the "calling class" gets that permission

Comment: I made some more tests.
In the calling class (CreateOption), I declare the semaphore like this: public static  Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(-2,true); (I'm using -2 and then I'll try with 3 elements).
Then, at the end of every Worker class, I put a CreateOption.sem.release() and, after the for that cycle all the elements, I try to acquire the semaphore.
This is what I'm trying to do, but it still freeze..

EDIT:
I'm updating the opening post so it will all be clearer!

Comment: http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=java+how+to+use+a+semaphore&qpvt=java+how+to+use+a+semaphore&FORM=VDRE

Comment: I know I might sounds like a lazy kid that rather ask on SO than search for tutorials, but I swear I'm not. I saw the video tutorials you linked, and they didn't help me much. It's almost working: the workers release the permits and the semaphore goes from 1-coda.size() to 1. The only wrong thing is that when I tell the method to acquire the semaphore it doesn't stop&wait for the other process to finish, it freeze everything. I'm sure I'm missing something and I'm sure is my fault; but I don't know where to look

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, use :

```
    //this will restart the for loop until the stop criteria 
    //is met 
    while (true){

        //the for loop 
        for (int i = 0; i<coda.size(); i++){
            //...........   
        }

        //stop criteria
      if (variable == coda.size())  break ;
    }//end of while loop
```

Comment: I tried it, and it keeps freezing.
That's quite similar to a single do-while, right? I think the point is that it's never refresh the variable value..